# Loading Opengl models into a container and calling them one after the other

Tags: c++, opengl, stl

I'm a newbie to programming and I want to write conditional statements for OpenGL models  such that when I click a button it loads a Triangle model in a stl vector container. When I click the same button again, it loads another model say Quad in the container, and for further button clicks it loads more models such as Cube, Toroid and so on....
I'm also going to include an Undo button to remove the last loaded model.

Can someone please guide me through writing such conditional statement on how to load about 4 models into the STL vector container for each button click, and also Undo the loading

```
class Shapes {
public:
    Shapes(){}
    ~Shapes(){}
    virtual void draw() 
    { 
        std::cout << "Base function called" << std::endl; 
    }

};

class Models : public Shapes 
{    
  public: Models() 
    {

    }

    ~Models() {}

    virtual void draw() 
    {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
            glLoadIdentity(); 
            glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f); 
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); 
               glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red color
               glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f); // Top
               glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Green color
               glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Bottom Left
               glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Blue color
               glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Bottom Right
            glEnd(); // End drawing the triangle


    }

};

Draw_All_models{

  std::vector<Shapes*> myObjects;

  myObjects.push_back(new Triangle());
  myObjects.push_back(new Quad());
  //more models...

  void RenderScene() 
  {
    std::vector<Shapes*>::iterator it;
    for(it = myObjects.begin() ; it != myObjects.end; ++it) (*it)->draw();
     }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? In the current form, it's too broad

Comment: Being a newbie to programming, I don't think you should start by wading into OpenGL. Start with something small and simple, build up practice and experience. Don't bite off more than you can chew.

Comment: The question is how can I load more models(like cube, toroid etc.- 4 models specifically including the triangle) into the STL vector container for each button click, and also Undo the loading

Comment: @user1128088: This *barely* has anything to do with OpenGL; your question is about how to put polymorphic objects into a std::vector.

Comment: Also, it's a duplicate of the last question you asked: [Conditional Statement for stacking opengl models into container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872663/conditional-statement-for-stacking-opengl-models-into-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to understand is, that OpenGL doesn't maintain a scene or models. All it does is drawing nice little points, lines or triangles to the screen upon your request. Once you got that mentally digested, things become obvious:

Store a list, where each element encodes what to draw where. Then you need some method that traverses the list (or array), and for each element dispatches into the right function (also written by you) to draw the geometry according to the data of the element.

For example in C++ you may have some base class `Model` from which you derive classes `Box`, `Sphere`, `Torus` and so on. `Model` defines a virtual method `draw`. Then you make a `std::list<Model*> models`, which you can iterate by `for(std::list<Model*> I = models.begin(); I != models.end(); I++){(*I)->draw();}`

The overridden virtual `draw` methods then take care of properly rendering each kind of model.